# 'NSUnknownKeyException' this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageViewLogotype

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Когда запускаю приложение возникает ошибка 
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageViewLogotype.'

аутлет imageViewLogotype который указан в ошибке везде подключен проверила Sourcecode этого xib файла и Сториборд не нашла там не используемых аутлетов все подключено

Добавила значек Inherit Module From Target

Проверила Compile Sources и Copy Bundle Resources файлы класса есть

Чистила DerivedData и делала Clean неоднократно

Пробовала удалить эту связь и подключить новую (с новым аутлетом была та же ошибка)

Я уже не знаю что пробовать (( Вернула проект в начальное состояние для этого вопроса  Помогите разобраться что не так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дополнительные скрины 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvrAR.png    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nexJ.png   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfkYU.png

Comment: Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте вот тут, может быть ваш ключ imageViewLogotype

[image]

---

и еще проблема может быть в том что ваш класс PDFView заменяет на системный из [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview)

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ , я проверила но к сожалению ключей там нет (

Comment: а если отключить атулет, то все ок ?

Comment: А если отключить то пишет что уже не в классе а в контроллере следующего аутлета не найдено  ATFileModifyViewController 0x10281c800> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageViewPhoto.                                                           Вылетает сразу после того как я в контроллере инициализирую объект класса PDFView   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZHuP.png

Comment: В начале вот такое предупреждение еще  Class PDFView is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/PDFKit.framework/PDFKit (0x1b0b444c0) and /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CDB50D7B-3860-4D28-AF74-47A0CA447A5A/AweryTags.app/AweryTags (0x100804050). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: апдейтнул ответ, проверьте, и лучше не называть свои классы как системные

Comment: Да проект писался давно и этот класс теперь стал по названию действительно как системный , в этом и была проблема , я переименовала класс и ошибка исчезла )) Спасибо большое за помощь !